# GORM / HQL - LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, grails, hql, grails-orm

in GORM (using grails) i need to combine in subselect multiple results into one value. (result of this subselect will be concatenated value on which i can make search / sort etc. ...)
Query is writen as HQL. Something like this in oracle
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php

Can be something like that achieved in HQL (e.g. GORM) ?

```
...
AND (
    SELECT LISTAG(e.title) AS con FROM Entity e
    WHERE Entity.searchKey = TRUE
    AND e.parrent = par
    AND LOWER(e.title) LIKE :search
) > 0
...
ORDER BY con ASC
```

thansk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate, and the HQL/GORM layers that sit on top of Hibernate, do not directly support database-specific functions like Oracle's `LISTAGG()`. There are, however, a few ways to use native SQL within Grails.  If you would like to add your concatenated value to one of your domain objects, you can use GORM's derived property feature (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties).

Something along these lines:

```
class MyDomain {
    Long parentId
    String titleAgg

    static mapping = {
        titleAgg formula: '(SELECT LISTAGG(e.title) FROM Entity e WHERE e.parrent = parent_id)'
    }

}
```

A second option would be to use the Grails-defined `dataSource` bean along with `groovy.sql.Sql` to execute native SQL statements.  See [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/03/grails-goodness-using-groovy-sql.html) for an example.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I think defined dataSource would work fine in my scenarion. Result of such sql is collection of GroovyRowResult (according to example in link you posted) -> so i would just need to map it after exection into my domain entities. But it will be simple while those entities has only 4 properties. Only problem i see is : my complex query is written in HQL (it`s dynamic etc. ...) -> i just need to find way how to convert HQL into nativeSQL and then i can add execute in way described upper.